# sql subqueries! problem with ANY operator in basic sql query. dont know why it is required in my query and how will it work?

Tags: sql, h2

I get the following error

> Scalar subquery contains more than one row; SQL statement: select * from trip where price= ( select price from hiking_trip ); [90053-193]

From the SQL

```
SELECT *
FROM trip
WHERE price =  (
  SELECT price
  FROM hiking_trip
);
```

I know the error disappears if I add `ANY` to my code after `=`. but I don't understand why it does not work? Shouldn't it give me the price equal to the given condition? and why `ANY` will make it work?

UPDATE: i got the point you told me but then

select *
from country
where exists
(
select *
  from mountain
  where 
  mountain.country_id=country.id
);

in this query won't the select *statement in subquery return more than one row or column yet it is working here??

Comment: The '=' operator expects the subquery to return one row. Use the 'IN' operator if the subquery returns more than 1 row.

Answer (score 0):

This fails because `=` is expecting a single value for the comparison, not a list of values which is what the `select` returns.  Technically, it wants a *scalar subquery* -- a subquery that returns 1 column and 0 or 1 rows.

You can fix the syntax problem in many ways.

Use aggregation to return one value:

```
WHERE trip.price = ( SELECT MAX(price) FROM hiking_trip )
```

Use `limit` to return one value:

```
WHERE trip.price = (SELECT price FROM hiking_trip LIMIT 1)
```

Use `in` to match any value:

```
WHERE trip.price IN (SELECT price FROM hiking_trip)
```

Use `any`:

```
WHERE trip.price = ANY (SELECT price FROM hiking_trip)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because the subquery `SELECT price FROM hiking_trip` returns multiple rows.

You would need to use `IN` instead of `=` for it to work.

```
SELECT * FROM trip WHERE price IN ( SELECT price FROM hiking_trip );
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because your subquery is returning more than one row.

You can use `IN` instead of `=`

```
SELECT * FROM trip WHERE price IN ( SELECT price FROM hiking_trip );
```

or you can use `LIMIT`

```
SELECT * FROM trip WHERE price = (SELECT price FROM hiking_trip LIMIT 1)
```

which will filter the subquery result with first row